# Propensity Score Matching w/ 3 levels Rx

Tags: survival, multinomial-distribution, propensity-scores, matching

I'm trying to match consecutive patients by fitting a Propensity Score. The treatment has 3 levels (Controls, Treat_1, Treat_2). The "MatcheIt" package, is designed to work only with 2 levels treatment. I tried with the "Twang" package, however it seems to be designed for Propensity adjusted analysis, not for matching. My outcome of interest is time to event and I need to plot survival curves and  I think that PS-matching may be superior to PS-adj.

Comment: Hi Gabriele, nice you are joining CV. Perhaps this post will be useful: stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202698/comparing-two-or-more-treatments-with-inverse-probablity-of-treatment-weighting/203771#203771

Comment: Gary King has papers criticizing using PS for matching and they are pretty compelling. He recommends using a mahalanobis distance function instead. See this ungated paper *Why Propensity Scores Should Not Be Used For Matching* here... http://gking.harvard.edu/files/gking/files/psnot.pdf?m=1456683191 And there's an even clearer explanation in his ICM webinar last fall ... http://thepoliticalmethodologist.com/2015/09/02/international-methods-colloquium-gary-king-talk-on-911-at-1200-noon-eastern-and-ay-2015-16-talk-schedule/